# Aggregate project results in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I got a sample group which can be constructed by following DSL:

```
g.addV('M').property(id, 'm1')
g.addV('A').property('pka', 'x').addE('e1').to(V('m1'))
g.addV('A').property('pka', 'y').addE('e1').to(V('m1'))
g.addV('D').property('pkb', 'z').addE('e2').to(V('m1'))
g.addV('M').property(id, 'm2')
g.addV('A').property('pka', 'p').addE('e1').to(V('m2'))
g.addV('D').property('pka', 'q').addE('e1').to(V('m2'))
```

I wanna to traversal from 'M' vertices, and get aggregate result of properties of the out connected vertices. As now, i can use:

```
g.V().hasLabel('M').
project('A', 'B').
    by(__.in('e1').values('pka').fold()).
        by(__.in('e2').values('pkb').fold())
```

to get results:

```
==>[A:[x,y],B:[z]]
==>[A:[q,p],B:[]]
```

Wanna to aggregate these results and finally get:

```
==>[A:[x,y,q,p],B:[z]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this from your original query by grouping the results:

```
g.V().hasLabel('M').
project('A', 'B').
by(__.in('e1').values('pka').fold()).
by(__.in('e2').values('pkb').fold()).
unfold().group().by(select(keys)).by(select(values).unfold().fold())
```

Or you can use `fold` before the `project` step:

```
g.V().hasLabel('M').
fold().
project('A', 'B').
by(unfold().in('e1').values('pka').fold()).
by(unfold().in('e2').values('pkb').fold())
```

I tested both solutions here: https://gremlify.com/2b